# Digital ocean on Laravel Forge - Unable to load key (navicat)

Tags: digital-ocean, navicat, laravel-forge

Im pulling my hair out with this one. I've managed to get a site running on Digital Ocean through Forge and also SSH into the server so I know that the SSH keys are setup correctly.

But when trying to connect via Navicat, I keep getting the error "Unable to load key". Does anyone know what this is in reference to or what the problem is.

regards

Answer (score 1):

There is [an answer](https://community.navicat.com/forum/navicat-product/navicat-for-mysql/3339-problem-connecting-to-server-via-ssh-tunnel) from 2015 on Navicat forum, indicating there could be issue with ssh key support.

If you can connect via ssh, do an ssh tunnel to your server manually:

```
ssh -v servername -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306 -N
```

Afterwards, you connect to remote mysql as it was on your localhost (you should not have one running on 3306, otherwise map to another local port)

Comment: can't believe if they still have this error support